# Is there a modern PHP framework as of 2015 that does not rely on Composer?

Tags: php

I'm on Shared Reselling hosting that does not allow me to customize my server directly, and have already asked about Composer. My Host states it would be a server-wide installation and thus they can't allow it, without upgrading to a Dedicated box which I cannot afford at this time.

I have done my research, and determined at very least that the top three frameworks require Composer to install while adjusting their downloadable files to match that. This is out of the question, and I'm looking for a few specific features:

- Theming
- Session Management
- Controller access - like controller/function or controller.function from URL and management of above, restricting access.
- Model View Controller Router style.
- and possibly database management

Can anyone offer any suggestions up? I know of Joomla and like it, but I don't need a full CMS on top of a framework for this project.

Comment: Often you do not need composer. It's just there to download all the files. You can either do it manullay or do it external to the server and transfer across in the normal way. There are plently of vps accounts for less than $50 a year of you need some sort of dedicated hardware

Comment: Not 100% sure but I think codeigniter does not use composer

Comment: Symfony does not require you to use composer. That said, there's no reason you can't use your local development to run composer and install everything you need, then sync everything. Or switch to a better host, there's plenty of affordable options that you could use.

Comment: I think the choice of framework and libraries is more important than the choice of a web hosting company. Do not let them limit yourself in chosen technologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use composer on your computer to develop your application, and then just copy all the files over to the server when you're ready. Composer itself need not be on the server for the application to run - it only downloads and generates some files. You really should try to take advantage of composer these days if you can, it makes it trivial to update libraries that you otherwise would be too lazy to do.

Comment: I do this for various projects. Just use `rsync` locally with a set of ignore patterns in a shell script, committed to the repo itself, and then run migrations on the server in an SSH session. I've no need to avoid Composer on the server, it's just convenient to do upgrades this way.

Comment: I decided to take this route, and grabbed a version of Xampp that matches my server setup. Now learning Composer.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to the existing answers, which is "don't use Composer", I wonder if you could just use a project-specific Composer? This does not need to be installed server-wide, and will work on any good quality shared hosting (there's probably a minimum required version of PHP, but you should be sticking to supported versions only anyway).

You'll need SSH though, but that's so useful I wouldn't recommend you use any hosting without it.

To install Composer locally, just run the installer in your project directory on the host:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```